# Can multiple columns be updated in a single update query

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

Hey I'm working on a logic in Oracle wherein I have procedure which inserts some data into a table.
But again i need to perform some operations on the columns , I know we can achieve this via cursor's but it will affect the throughput time of the procedure.

Just wanted to know if single update will work for this scenario.

-----something of this sort----------

```
Update tablename 
Set column_2 = case when colum_2 = 0 then column_1 else column_2 end,
Column_3  =case when colum_3 = 0 then column_ 2 else column_ 3 end ;
```

Comment: Yes. Try it out.

Comment: Yes the basic aim of updating here is , a single row can have 10-12 columns (consider for example) and i don't want any column to have zero value , it should be updated with the previous column value.

Thanks a lot guys this worked !!

Answer (score -1):

I can't say whether it will "work" because you haven't said what you are hoping the results will be.

All the expressions on the right hand side of the equals sign will be use their values as they were prior to the update.

So, for example,

```
Set column_2 = case when colum_2 = 0 then column_1 else column_2 end,
    Column_3  =case when colum_3 = 0 then column_ 2 else column_ 3 end
```

... will never cause `Column_3` to get a value that was originally in `Column_1`, which one might be afraid of if both `Column_2` and `Column_3` where originally equal to zero.

That won't happen.  If both `Column_2` and `Column_3` where originally equal to zero, then `Column_2` will be set to the original value of `Column_1`, and `Column_3` will get set to the original value of `Column_2` (which we've already said was zero).

If, when both columns are zero, you wanted both columns to get the value of `Column_1`, you would have had to write it like this:

```
SET column_2 = case when column_2 = 0 then column_1 else column_2 end,
    column_3 = case when column_3 = 0 
                  then 
                     case when column_2 = 0 THEN column_1 ELSE column_2 end
                  else 
                     column_3 end
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand what you really want but an UPDATE can update the value of more than one column on the row in one single UPDATE statement:
UPDATE table_name set col01 = , col02 =, etc... WHERE